# Firebase JSON structure for a Social App

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made simple JSON struct for posts and users in Firebase:

```
posts
   UID
    postKey
      content: 
      postId: 
      postImageStringUrl:
      profileImageUrl: 
      timestamp: 
      username: 

users
   UID
     email: 
     profileImageUrl: 
     reputation: 
     username:
```

I would like to know is it okay to do? Like this I know only how to query posts by UID but do not know how to query all posts that doesn't belong to current user. Is it possible like this to see other user profile?

Like this I should query only spcific user posts:

```
databaseRef.child("posts").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).observe(.value, with: { (posts) in

            var newPostsArray = [Post]()
            for post in posts.children {

                let newPost = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newPostsArray.insert(newPost, at: 0)
            }

            self.postsArray = newPostsArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

For posts I have struct like this(minimal):

```
class Post: NSObject {
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var key: String!

    init( key: String = "") {

        self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }



    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.ref = snapshot.ref


    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any] {

        return ["postImageStringUrl": postImageUrl as Any,"profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl as Any, "content": content as Any,"username": username as Any,"postId":postId as Any, "timestamp": timestamp as Any]
    }
}
```

What the app does?:

1. Can register, login
2. Can see feed or posts and make them
3. Want to let user to like posts
4. Want user to see other user profiles

Comment: Can you explain your app-structure, and what your app will be all about.. Its hard to comment before knowing that.. :)

Comment: I added some details :)

Answer (score 1):

Like what I have told you in the other thread, you could query the Post per person using a function like the following:

```
func loadPosts(userID: String) {

        let usersRef = firebase.child("Posts").child(userID)
        usersRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            if snapshot.exists() {

                self.tweets.removeAll()

                let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date",ascending: false)])

                for element in sorted {

                    let message = element.valueForKey("message")! as? String
                    let userID = element.valueForKey("backendlessObjectID")! as? String
                    let name = element.valueForKey("name")! as? String
                    let date = element.valueForKey("date")! as? String

                    let t = Tweet(message: message!, userID: userID!, name: name!, date: date!)

                    self.tweets.append(t)                  
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData() 
        })            
 }
```

Then you call the function either with:

```
loadPosts(currentUserID)
```

Or you first gather all the Users that actually did a post, store their IDs into an Array of `var userIDs: [String] = []` and then loop through this Array.

```
for user in userIDs {
   loadPosts(user)
}
```

That way you're getting all the Posts for all Users.

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar app once, JSON tree structure i used was :-

```
myApp :{
  Users :{
    userID1 :{
      userName : userName1,
      userLocation : New York,
      },

      FriendID1 : {....},

      FriendID2 : {....},
      ..
     },

  friendsListOfUsers :{
      userID1 : {
         friendID1 : true,
         friendID2 : true,
         friendID3 : true,
         ... 
        },
        .. 
     },  

  postsCreatedByUser : {
       userID1 :{
         myPostID1 : true,
         myPostID2 : true,
            },
       FriendID1 :{
         myFriends1PostID1 : true
            },
       FriendID2 :{
         myFriends2PostID1 : true
            },
       FriendID3 :{
         myFriends3PostID1 : true
            }, 
           },   

  postsIdsToShowInFeed : {
       userID1 :{
         myFriends1PostID1 : true,         //Posts created by this user's friends
         myFriends2PostID1 : true,
         myFriends3PostID1 : true,
         myPostID1 : true,                //Posts created by the user itself
         myPostID2 : true
            },
        FriendsID1 : {...}, 
           },  

 postsCreatedByTheAuthenticatedUsers : {

         myFriend1PostID1 : {Posts Details....},         //Posts created by this user's friends
         myFriend2PostID1 : {Posts Details....},         //Posts created by this user's friends
         myFriend3PostID1 : {Posts Details....},         //Posts created by this user's friends
         myPostID1 : {Posts Details....},                //Posts created by the user itself
         myPostID2 : {Posts Details....},

        }
     }
```

To tackle the **Users Friends Unique ID** problem , i used a hack to integrate the users ID with the **timestamp** and set it as a **postsId's**.

And while retrieving the data from the **`postsIdsToShowInMyFeed`** , extract the uniqueID from **postID** and then access that users **`postsCreatedByTheAuthenticatedUsers`** node.

### For PostID

```
   let timeStamp = Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate*1000)
   let newPost = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)+" + "\(timeStamp)"
```

Your postId will look something like this:-

```
   WDfIyaJ***************2iw82+495671998919
```

where *495671998919* is your timestamp

### Post Retrieval

```
let feedFriendID = "\(postKey[postKey.startIndex..<postKey.characters.index(postKey.startIndex, offsetBy: postKey.characters.count - 13)])"          // 13 because `+495671998919` is of 13 character length
let friendPath = "postsCreatedByTheAuthenticatedUsers/\(feedFriendID)"
```

---

Every time any users friend or the user itself makes a post , the post details are saved like this:-

- If the currentUser makes a post it gets saved in these nodes :-

  - **`postsCreatedByUser`** of the current user  -> Only post key
  - **`postsIdsToShowInFeed`**  of the current user  -> Only post key
  - **`postsCreatedByTheAuthenticatedUsers/userId`**   -> [post key : post Details]
- If a currentUser's friends makes a post it gets saved in these nodes :-

  - **`postsIdsToShowInFeed`**  of the current user  -> Only post key  (You will have to loop over through every friendsID and do this)
  - **`postsCreatedByTheAuthenticatedUsers/friendID`**   -> [post key : post Details]

Comment: Isn't here too much nesting?

Comment: This is the flattest JSON you could get for a social app.. Also i am removing the uniqueID's from the **`postsCreatedByTheAuthenticatedUsers`** node but then you gotta manipulate your security rules such that, The current user should only be able to access those key's which are in its **postsIdsToShowInFeed** node